# React | Lifting State Up

Tags: reactjs

```
render() {
    const scale = this.state.scale;
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    const celsius = scale === 'f' ? tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius) : temperature;
    const fahrenheit = scale === 'c' ? tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit) : temperature;

    return (
      <div>
            <TemperatureInput
          scale="c"
          temperature={celsius}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleCelsiusChange} />
             <TemperatureInput
          scale="f"
          temperature={fahrenheit}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleFahrenheitChange} />
            <BoilingVerdict
          celsius={parseFloat(celsius)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/WZpxpz?editors=0010

Am I right? When we perform an action in the form, for example, in the 1st, an event occurs that changes the internal state of the calculator immediately to scale = c and then a comparison occurs, that is, our this.state = scale is already equal to C and C should be equal to === f so scale=C(celsius) is converted to (Fahrenheit)

Comment: We need a bit more information about what you need. The start of your code example also doesn't appear to have copied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does use a class-based react component which has valid logic.

However, the code can be optimized and transformed into a functional React component with a reduction in the number of lines.

```js
const scaleNames = { c: 'Celsius', f: 'Fahrenheit'};

const toCelsius = (fahrenheit) => (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
const toFahrenheit = (celsius) => (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;

const tryConvert = (temperature, convert) => {
  const input = parseFloat(temperature);
  if (Number.isNaN(input)) return '';
  const output = convert(input);
  const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded.toString();
}

const BoilingVerdict = ({celsius}) => (celsius >= 100 ? <p>The water would boil.</p> : <p>The water would not boil.</p>);
const TemperatureInput = ({temperature, scale, onTemperatureChange}) => (
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleNames[scale]}:</legend>
    <input value={temperature} onChange={(e) => onTemperatureChange(e.target.value)} />
  </fieldset>
);

const Calculator = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({temperature: '', scale: 'c'});
  const handleChange = (scale, temperature) => setState({scale: scale, temperature});
  
  const {scale, temperature} = state;
  const celsius = scale === 'f' ? tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius) : temperature;
  const fahrenheit = scale === 'c' ? tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit) : temperature;

  return (
    <div>
      <TemperatureInput
        temperature={celsius}
        onTemperatureChange={(t) => handleChange('c', t)} />
      <TemperatureInput
        temperature={fahrenheit}
        onTemperatureChange={(t) => handleChange('f', t)} />
      <BoilingVerdict
        celsius={parseFloat(celsius)} />
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Calculator/>);
```

But still, there is an issue with the `<TemperatureInput/>` component being re-rendered twice. To optimize this, the use of `useMemo` hook can be employed.

```js
import "./styles.css";

import React from 'react';
import { useMemo } from "react";
const scaleNames = { c: 'Celsius', f: 'Fahrenheit'};
const toCelsius = (fahrenheit) => (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
const toFahrenheit = (celsius) => (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
const tryConvert = (temperature, convert) => {
  const input = parseFloat(temperature);
  if (Number.isNaN(input)) return '';
  const output = convert(input);
  const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded.toString();
}

const BoilingVerdict = ({celsius}) => (celsius >= 100 ? <p>The water would boil.</p> : <p>The water would not boil.</p>);
const TemperatureInput = ({temperature, scale, onTemperatureChange}) => {
  const scaleName = useMemo(() => scaleNames[scale], [scale]);
  return (
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleName}:</legend>
      <input value={temperature} onChange={(e) => onTemperatureChange(e.target.value)} />
    </fieldset>
  );
};

export default function App() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({temperature: '', scale: 'c'});
  const handleChange = (scale, temperature) => setState({scale: scale, temperature});
  const {scale, temperature} = state;

  const celsius = useMemo(() => {
    return scale === 'f' ? tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius) : temperature;
  }, [scale, temperature]);
  
  const fahrenheit = useMemo(() => {
    return scale === 'c' ? tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit) : temperature;
  }, [scale, temperature]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <TemperatureInput
        temperature={celsius}
        onTemperatureChange={(t) => handleChange('c', t)} />
      <TemperatureInput
        temperature={fahrenheit}
        onTemperatureChange={(t) => handleChange('f', t)} />
      <BoilingVerdict celsius={parseFloat(celsius)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```